# Dynamically switch ng-include and ng-controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-ng-include

I have a section on my page with a few tabs which have to include a partial and controller. 
I would like to dynamically switch a ng-include and ng-controller based on the current tab selected.

Probably the biggest issue here is that Angular expects a controller to point to the actually controller and not to a string with the controller name.

I tried a few different things, but I can not get it to work.

```
$scope.tab.active = {
    view: 'activetabview.html',
    controller: 'ActiveTabController'
}

<section ng-include src="tab.active.view" ng-controller="tab.active.controller">
</section>
```

Comment: Why not load the ng-controller bit inside your partial? E.g. in `activetabview.html`

Comment: @DaniëlSmink sure this would be a possibility and actually how I am doing it right now.   
But what I would like to do is define an array of tabs like this: 
`["Foo", "Bar"]` and have that resolved to the following views: `foo.html`, `bar.html` and controllers: `FooController` and `BarController`.

Comment: Maybe using ui-router would be helpful for you it allows nested views. And you could have secondary routing for your tabs. Check out: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views

Comment: @DaniëlSmink tnx, that looks really promising! I'll have a look into that right now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Routing method.

I Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am already using routing for my views, is it possible to use a routing method inside a view?

Comment: Am not sure that this is good way or not. You can take flag that 'activeTab' global scope variable based on the flag hide and show the tabs.